# ValueError at /issue/1/comment Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: miko>>"

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to create a simple Comment feature for a blog app. In the Class-based views, if you are using a Foreign Key in your model, I know that you have to override the def form_valid: in order for the Comment to be posted by the current logged-in User.

I did this for the Blog model in my app, and it works just as intended, however, when I try to do the same with the CommentCreateView, I get the error.

Here's my code so far

views.py

```
class IssueCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Issue
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'mark_as', 'assignee', 'priority', 'label']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    template_name = 'issues/add_comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.issue = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                              related_name='comments')
    
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('issue-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('issue-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

What did I do wrong?

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 71, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 174, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 144, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_app\issues\views.py", line 100, in form_valid
    form.instance.issue = self.request.user
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 215, in __set__
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /issue/1/comment
Exception Value: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: miko>>": "Comment.issue" must be a "Issue" instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `CommentCreateView`, you assign the Request User (a Django User database object located at `django.contrib.auth.User` to the empty field Issue on Comment.

But Issue requires an Issue model from `bug_app.issues.models.Issue`.

```py
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    template_name = 'issues/add_comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.issue = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

A possible fix is to:

1. Ensure that the Issue is created before the Comment is.
2. When creating the comment, either as a URL Parameter or POST Parameter, pass in the Primary Key of the Issue.
3. Assign that value (an integer) to the Issue instead of the User.